# error with clearcontent/clearcontents and keeping formulas

Tags: google-apps-script

having trouble with the following code:

```
function addDelivery() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7");

  var range = srcSheet.getRange("B3:L3").getValues();
  var formulas = srcSheet.getRange("B3:L3").getFormulas();
  srcSheet.insertRowBefore(6);
  srcSheet.getRange(6,2,1,11).setValues(range);
  range.clearContents();
  range.setFormulas(formulas);
```

I want to clear the contents of cells B3:L3 but keep the formula in L3.

I get the error message "TypeError: range.clearContent is not a function".
I read that clearContent is a method of Range and clearContents is a method of sheet.
I've tried both, but neither work.

Please help.

Best regards
manc

Comment: The problem is that you declared `var range=srcSheet.getRange('B3:L3").getValues()` so range is not an object of Class Range.   It's a 2D array of values.

Comment: Also Range only has method clearContent()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this would work better:

```
function addDelivery() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7");
  var range=srcSheet.getRange("B3:L3");  
  var values = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  srcSheet.insertRowBefore(6);
  srcSheet.getRange(6,2,1,11).setValues(values);
  range.setFormulas(formulas);
  srcSheet.getRange("B3:K3").clearContent();
```

I thought about it some more and I think I'd probably do it this way:

```
  function addDelivery() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7");
  var range = srcSheet.getRange("B3:L3");  
  var values = range.getValues();
  var formula = srcSheet.getRange("L3").getFormula();
  srcSheet.insertRowBefore(6);
  srcSheet.getRange(6,2,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
  srcSheet.getRange("L3").setFormula(formula);
  srcSheet.getRange("B3:K3").clearContent();
```

Comment: you're 2 for 2 :) Thanks very much. So the way the range was called to set the values in (6,2,1,11), the same method applies to call getRange to clearContent.

Comment: You could have made that line `srcSheet.getRange(6,2,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);` which saves you the trouble of having to figure out how big it is.

Comment: So it looks like you're collecting data in line 3 and then moving  down to a lifo in line 6 and then clearing line 3 for new data.

Comment: Exactly right Cooper.Thank-you for your help and efforts. If row 6 onwards is part of a named range, every time a row is added, the named range moves as well - it doesn't stay at row 6 even when i define the range as $B$6:M - it changes to B7:M, B8:M etc. How can i hard code the range to stay at B6:M?